# Internal error while connecting to google play services

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

I`m trying to connect to Google Play Services as is stated in [developer](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html) documentation, but it does not connect and I got connect Result code 8 that means that An internal error occurred. Retrying should resolve the problem.

Why this problem happened and what is an internal error? How to resolve that?

Comment: what device are you tring on? Many don't support googlePlayServices and you need to account for this fact and act accordingly

Comment: I run my code on emulator on platform 5.1.1 and API level 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I recolved my problem easily.
it was a VPN problem that confused android studio. I turned it off and problem solved.